# Deny direct access to success url in ecommerce website by typing it

Tags: php, redirect, paypal, ccavenue

**Bottom Line:** How do I prevent direct access to the success page when the transaction is done (FileName is `ThankYou.php`) if he/she knows the `URL`. I have integrated `ccAvenue Payment Gateway` in my application.

**Full Detail:** I have made an eCommerce web application (still under construction).

On the checkout page, whenever user clicks the `proceed to payment` button, I am generating a unique `OrderCode` and saving it in a session and calling that session value in the success url page and inserting all the details in the order table and if `OrderCode` is not set, I am heading the user away to the `//www.example.com/store/`

Now, suppose he knows the success `url` (`//www.example.com/store/ThankYou.php`) where `ccAvenue` is redirecting after the successful payment of the amount to the merchant, types `URL` directly. I want that user should not directly access it by typing it in the URL bar, but when the payment is done, the `ThankYou.php` file has to be shown for only 2 minutes and not more than that. And after 2 minutes, if he tries to access the success url page again, he should not see that success page again.

After a bit of research, many of them have said to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` which to my knowledge can be bypassed if the user tries to do.

So how do I achieve this ?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: At ThankYou.php page are you storing some value in DB?

Comment: Yes.. Only the delivery address of the customer and nothing else.

Comment: use session flash variables.

Comment: @itachi Please elaborate

Comment: Are you clearing session value for OrderCode after inserting data in DB.

Comment: Yes, I am clearing everything from the session except the customer's login data..

Comment: you can also check the referrer url and display information after verify.

Comment: You mean `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` ?

Answer (score 0):

After the successful payment, CCavenue will redirect to our successurl with the some details as post url/get url.

Whet you need to do on the top of thankyou.php page get the any unique value from return parameters,

In If block check is set that parameter and delivery address against that particular customer is not find in database than display thankyou message and Save delivery address of the customer.

In else block just redirect to any other page so customer if hit again same url of thankyou page than he/she cannot see the page instead it will take to redirected page.

Comment: Sir, can you please elaborate your point, I am unable to find the clear logic in your answer.

Comment: 1 - Step
did you able get the CCavenue parameters on thankyou page when anyone do transaction.??

CCavenue will be return some information to thankyou page with post or get method after make payment. If you are able to get that all info than let me know.?